# What is more appropriate - a series of planned t-test or planned contrasts over a model?

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, panel-data, multiple-comparisons

Let's assume I want to compare two approaches to servicing some electric device. I have some performance indicator and I measure it over time, repeatedly.

There are 10 measurements + baseline (before any procedure), but I want to compare the methods only at time t5, t8 and t10.

That's what I can plan.

**Option 1**
I can test it using 3 t unpaired t-tests (between methods) with appropriate correction.
Pros: This is simple and free from model misspecification. It compares **raw data means**, the empirical cell means.

Cons: it ignores the information that the 3 measurements come from a single device.

or

**Option 2:**
A linear model accounting for the within-device correlation. Either the generalized-least-square (GLS) estimated linear model with unstructured covariance, or the linear mixed model.

Pros: this account for the correlated outcomes. Having a model ready, I can employ the method of testing contrasts to test whatever I want. It uses also all the available data, possible making the calculations more reliable.

Cons: the comparison involves the LS-means, which are based on the model. And the model may be misspecified, for example non-linear or so. The calculations are not based on data directly, but on some model instead.

Let's assume I am completely clueless researcher here. I don't precisely know what I should use to do my analysis.

Simple series of Holm-adjusted t-tests seems easy, refers to the real, raw data and does not rely on any model. It cannot be "spoiled" easily.

The model based approach uses more data, catches the internal relationships, is flexible, but sensitive to model misspecification.

I wanted to report both, but on a different forum I was told to not doing it, because what to do, if both will give opposite results? For example, the t-test at t5 will give small magnitude of difference and lack of statistical significance, and the test over the model at t5 will give bigger magnitude?

So, which one is better from a scientific perspective? Please enlighten me a bit!